# Cannot read external Fotos Library with MediaLibrary framework

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave, media-library

I'm trying to read a Fotos Library with the MediaLibrary framework from an external disc ("`/Seagate`").
Whatever I try out, I only get the data from the default library which is located under "Pictures"

Reading the external library with Fotos app runs perfectly. ( I changed the path in Fotos)
In my app, I tried several options:

1. connecting to the `MediaLibrary` using the options dictionary to
   include my external device by MLMediaLoadFoldersKey ( see code below). no success
2. reading `mediaGroups` with different identifiers. no success

I wonder why I cannot get 2 `mediaSources`, though I have defined the default folders and my external one

The aspect of lazy loading data from the library should be managed well, as I have set observers for all the steps: `library -> sources -> groups -> objects`

To point 1:

```
 NSDictionary *options = @{
                              MLMediaLoadSourceTypesKey: @(MLMediaSourceTypeImage),
                              MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey: @[MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier,MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier],
                              MLMediaLoadFoldersKey:@[MLMediaLoadFoldersKey,@"//Seagate/Fotos Library"]

    if ( mediaLibrary == Nil) {
        MLMediaLibrary *MmediaLibrary = [[MLMediaLibrary alloc] initWithOptions:options];
        mediaLibrary = MmediaLibrary;
    }

    [mediaLibrary addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"mediaSources"
                      options:0
                      context:(__bridge void *)@"mediaLibraryLoaded"];

    [mediaLibrary mediaSources];
```

To point 2:

```
//...
    else if (context == (__bridge void *)@"rootMediaGroupLoaded")
    {
        MLMediaGroup *sharedAlbums   = [mediaSource mediaGroupForIdentifier:@"TopLevelAlbums"];
        MLMediaGroup *topLevelAlbums = [mediaSource mediaGroupForIdentifier:@"Albums"];
        MLMediaGroup *allFotosAlbums = [mediaSource mediaGroupForIdentifier:@"Fotos"];
        MLMediaGroup *iPhotoAlbums   = [mediaSource mediaGroupForIdentifier:@"iPhotos"];
        NSArray *albumList = [sharedAlbums.childGroups arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:topLevelAlbums.childGroups];
        albumList = [albumList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:allFotosAlbums.childGroups];
        albumList = [albumList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:iPhotoAlbums.childGroups];
        //albumList = [albumList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[topLevelAlbums]];

        {

            [self addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"nextAlbumIndex"
                      options:0
                      context:@"nextAlbumIndex"]; // manages the loop over all albums

#pragma mark query all photos of one Album
            //
            MLMediaGroup *Nalbum = [[AlbumList objectAtIndex:nextAlbumIndex] group];
            [Nalbum addObserver:self
                     forKeyPath:@"mediaObjects"
                        options:0
                        context:@"mediaObjects"];

            [Nalbum mediaObjects];  // query the list and store result in Malbum
        }}
}
```

I expect to retrieve the external Fotos library, but I always get the default one. 
There is no error message, which could give me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting Apple Support, I was told that reading Fotos library from another path  than the default one is not yet supporrted.